# DispatchKeyEvent not working on Fragment?

Tags: android

**Dispatch key event** method not working on Fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: getCurrentFragment in Activity and get the dispatchKeyEvent from Activity class and call your method in fragment

Answer (score 0):

dispatchKeyEvent is not a Fragment method, therefore you cannot override it.

What you can do is override it in your Activity and then call a method in your Fragment.